# Uploaded CSV file shows Date column as strings, how to convert to Dates for AutoAI use?

Tags: csv, date, format, ibm-cloud

I was trying out the AutoAI feature on the IBM cloud with a CSV that only has two columns: a date column and a change column (1 or 0). When I upload it, as a data asset, it sees the Date column as a string. Even after going through data refinery and converting it to a date, when AutoAI reads the file, it still sees it as a column of strings.

How do I make AutoAI recognize the date column as a column?

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
> Unfortunately , date recognition doesn't work on AutoAI at this moment. However, next year there is going to be an update of the autoai service where you will be able to have that feature. If you want to test it, there is a demo version of that: https://autoai.mybluemix.net/home
> Blockquote

Just to add a comment to Aleksandar's comment regarding the AutoAI Demo: it is a research demo thus it is not exposed to the general public. It needs further authorization (either an IBM w3id or a special login/pwd through an IBM sales representative).

And to answer the question, we are fully aware the user needs for the TS dataset and the Date/Time detection function, and it will be out very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , date recognition doesn't work on AutoAI at this moment. However, next year there is going to be an update of the autoai service where you will be able to have that feature. If you want to test it, there is a demo version of that: https://autoai.mybluemix.net/home

Answer (score 0):

The time series support is not in place yet. There is on-going effort to have first version available this year.
There is workaround option but not perfect (AutoAI will NOT treat data as timeseries):

- do the preprocessing / features creation on your own (create features like year, month, day, week etc.)
- pass such preprocessed data to AutoAI

Drawbacks: it will not be treated as ts data. Model validation (cross-validation), folds building will not take into account time order what may lead to unreliable metrics values.